# spring batch parellel processing using partitioner

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

process many files with limited number of threads not working properly.After completion of task that thread cannot be re-used.Enable to pass multiple files to limited number of threads.

```
@Bean
    public Step orderStep1() throws IOException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("orderStep1")
                .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner())
                .step(slaveStep())
                .gridSize(40)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor1())
                 .build();
    }
@Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor1() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor1 = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor1.setCorePoolSize(30);
    return taskExecutor1;
}
 @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<GPRSDAO> reader( 
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['file']}") String file 
            ) { 
         reader = new FlatFileItemReader<GPRSDAO>();
         reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(file));
            reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<GPRSDAO>() {
              {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                  {
                     setNames(new String[] { "firstName","lastName"  });
                  }
                });
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<GPRSDAO>() {
                  {
                    setTargetType(GPRSDAO.class);
                  }
                });
              }
            }); 
            reader.close();
         return reader; }

Input files=100(set dynamically during runtime using stepExecutionContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

> After completion of task that thread cannot be re-used.Enable to pass multiple files to limited number of threads.

You set the core pool size to 30 but did not set the [maxPoolSize](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setMaxPoolSize-int-) parameter. You need to set the max pool size to limit the number of threads.